# how to add a view button in table ?

Tags: php

In my script i want to add a view link that  will redirect to me next page and show the values of that perticuler field ...

out put of my script is like this-:

```
username1   1086769     view complete details
********    *******     view complete details
```

so if i click on view complete details of row 1 .. then i want full details of  username1 in next page like d_mail , d_phone  etc.

```
include 'config.php';
    $list="select d_name,d_amount from donated where d_apprv= 1 order by d_id desc limit 10;";
    $data=mysqli_query($con,$list); 
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr><td>" ."<strong>NAME OF DONER(s)</strong>" . "</td><td>" . "<strong>AMOUNT      DONATED</strong>" . "</td></tr>";
   while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
    {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $info['d_name'] . "</td><td>" . $info['d_amount'] . "</td><td>"."<a  href='view.php'>view complete details</a>" ."</td></tr>";
     }   
  echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Use another `td` with a link having get params?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I commented, it seems like you are already using a link like `<a  href='view.php'>view complete details</a>` but you aren't passing any values in that, so you should do it like

```
<a href='view.php?user_id='<?php echo $info['user_id_column_name']; ?>>view complete details</a>
```

And then on another page, use the value of `user_id` to pull the relevant data from the database using `$_GET['user_id']`.

Don't forget to sanitize value retrieved using `$_GET` before pulling the details from DB

Comment: what does it means very simple words..'Don't forget to sanitize value retrieved using $_GET before pulling the details from DB'

Comment: @user3292058 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php